# How to tell if our Dell PowerConnect 3524 has PoE?

Tags: switch, network, power-over-ethernet, powerconnect

First of all, I'm a web designer, not a network engineer, so simple answers are appreciated! We have someone coming in to sort out the network in the office and he has asked whether our Dell PowerConnect 3524 is in fact a 3524P Model. On the front of the unit, it just says 3524, but so do all the images I've seen of the 3524P model. Is there a way I can tell which model we have?

Comment: Can you log in to the switch?

Comment: I'm not sure, how would go about doing that?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to this, the P means PoE
http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pwcnt/en/pwcnt_3500_spec.pdf

You could also search support.dell.com with the serial number on the switch and it should tell you exactly what model it is.